# Formato de Fecha única

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola gente como están? Mi pregunta radica en que quiero estandarizar el formato ingresado.
Ya sea cuando se ingresa sin el 0 (cero) o con el o (cero).
Y la salida quiero que la saque `%%(dia)%%(mes)%%(año)`
Solamente la puedo sacarla literal como se ingresa. Hay alguna otra forma? intente con `.replace`, pero no pude.

Dejo el código para que lo vean.

```
print("Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento... \nPor ejemplo 01/02/2021 o 1/2/2021")
nacimiento = (input("Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento: "))

fecha = nacimiento.split("/")
dia = fecha[0]
mes = fecha[1]
anio = fecha[2]

completo = f"Su fecha de nacimiento es {dia} del {mes} del año {anio}."
#print(completo)

print(completo)
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con un `if`, determinando la longitud de la cadena ingresada con `len()` y si hace falta, concatenarle un cero antes de mostrarla:

```
print("Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento... \nPor ejemplo 01/02/2021 o 1/2/2021")
nacimiento = (input("Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento: "))

fecha = nacimiento.split("/")
dia = fecha[0]
mes = fecha[1]
anio = fecha[2]

if len(dia)==1:dia = '0' + dia;
if len(mes)==1:mes = '0' + mes;

completo = f"Su fecha de nacimiento es {dia} del {mes} del año {anio}."
#print(completo)

print(completo)
```

Puedes también utilizar un modificador en la cadena para darle al formato la longitud que deseas, en este caso `:02d` hace el trabajo, pero requiere que las variables sean enteros, por lo que aplico la conversión `int()` correspondiente al asignar el valor a cada variable:

```
print("Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento... \nPor ejemplo 01/02/2021 o 1/2/2021")
nacimiento = (input("Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento: "))

fecha = nacimiento.split("/")
dia = int(fecha[0])
mes = int(fecha[1])
anio = int(fecha[2])

completo = "Su fecha de nacimiento es {:02d} del {:02d} del año {:04d}.".format(dia, mes, anio)
#print(completo)

print(completo)
```

En ambos casos la salida es la misma:

```
Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento... 
Por ejemplo 01/02/2021 o 1/2/2021
Ingrese su fecha de nacimiento: 1/1/2021
Su fecha de nacimiento es 01 del 01 del año 2021.
```

Sin embargo, cada una fallará de distinta manera si se ingresan datos inválidos.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras de hacer esto, dependiendo de lo que quieres. Puedes usar [zfill](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) para rellenar con ceros a la izquierda, o formateando con fstrings.

Con zfill:

```
>>> nacimiento = '12/3/2003'
>>> fecha = nacimiento.split('/')
>>> fecha
['12', '3', '2003']
>>>
>>> fecha[1].zfill(2)
03
>>> dia = fecha[0].zfill(2)
>>> mes = fecha[1].zfill(2)
>>> print(f"Su fecha de nacimiento es {dia} del {mes} del año {fecha[2]}.")
Su fecha de nacimiento es 12 del 03 del año 2005.
```

Formateando directamente con fstrings:

Debido a que día y mes son cadenas y no números enteros, no se puede hacer un relleno de esta forma:

```
>>> a = 3 # ejemplo con un num entero cualquiera
>>> print(f'{a:02d}') # d especifica que es un entero
03
>>>
>>> print(f'{fecha[1]:02d}')
ValueError: Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str'
```

Tendrías que convertir los valores a entero `int(valor)` y aplicarle el formato como se muestra, o también se puede (un poco más avanzado) formatear como si fueras a [Alinear una Cadena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234445/format-output-string-right-alignment):

```
>>> dia = fecha[0]
>>> mes = fecha[1]
>>> anio = fecha[2]
>>> print(f"Su fecha de nacimiento es {dia:{0}>2} del {mes:{0}>2} del año {anio}.")
Su fecha de nacimiento es 12 del 03 del año 2005.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, también me sirvió de esta forma. Ahí estaba leyendo sobre zfil para ver como funciona.